# Load balance large number of https POST calls in Vert.x

Tags: vert.x

I am looking to build a Java backend that services an incoming REST call by making a large of https POST requests to other http servers.  A REST call will translate to aggregating the data from several 1000 https POST requests. Since I am looking to scale to several thousand remote http servers I am evaluating Vert.x to help do event driven, non-blocking https post requests.

I'd like to know the best approach to distribute these POST requests to my Verticals. I do see several examples of Verticals implementing http server requests with each Vertical waking up to a connect event. However I do not see any examples for http client Vertical load balancing in Vert.x.

One approach would be to have Verticals synchronize their access to a Producer Consumer queue but it would not be a good idea to have blocking code in a Vertical.

Comment: Can't you just deploy multiple instances of your module?

Answer (score 0):

Your best guess might be using createHTTPServer and/or RouteMatcher included by Vert.x. The great thing about either, is that they dynamically scale with zero-configuration. Any other services must be defined at a load-balancing level, but Vert.x does this for you with HTTP servers.

If you're looking to deploy your application from multiple machines, you might want to look into Hazelcast (Vert.x uses this in it's core libraries, so it's packed with Vert.x) http://www.hazelcast.com